# If a function defined on a compact set ${\cal X}$ to ${\mathbb R}$ (with no points undefined), then is this function bounded on ${\cal X}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, compactness

Let ${\cal X}$ be a compact set in Euclidean space, and $f: {\cal X} \to {\mathbb R}$ is a function with $|f(x)| < \infty$ for all $x \in {\cal X}$.

The question is whether we can find a $L \in {\mathbb R}_+$ such that $|f(x)| < L$ holds for all $x \in {\cal X}$?

Comment: If $f$ is any function, we cannot deduce something from this.

Comment: @StefanHamcke Thanks, and is there any nonexamples?

Comment: $f(0)=0,\, f(x)=1/x$ for $1\ge x>0$ is unbounded

Comment: @StefanHamcke Thank you very much :-)

Comment: What you need is continuity - for a continuous function, the bound at a point propagates to a neighbourhood. On a compact set, only finitely many such neighbourhoods matter, so a single bound works.